# Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor.You can have an empty constructor

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - java.util.List

> this is my DAO

```
 @Query(
        "select b.* " +
                " ,g.id_bordereau,g.id_nat_essence,g.id_nat_couleur ,g.numero_plaquette,g.id_nat_complement,g.localisation_libelle" +
                " from bille b  join  grume g on g.id_grume=b.id_grume " +
                "where g.id_bordereau = :idBordereau  "+
                "Group by b.id_grume " +
                "order By id_bille DESC , ordre ASC "
    )
    @Transaction
    suspend fun getAllBillesByBordereau(idBordereau: String): List<GrumeBillesEntity>
```

> this is my GrumeBillesEntity

```
data class GrumeBillesEntity(
    @Embedded val billes: List<BilleEntity>,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id_grume",
    entityColumn="id_grume"
    )
    val grume:Grume
    )
```

I get this error and I don't know how to correct it

Comment: You should ask clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try provide default params for values or an empty constructor for example:

```
data class GrumeBillesEntity(
@Embedded val billes: List<BilleEntity> = emptyList(),
@Relation(
    parentColumn = "id_grume",
entityColumn="id_grume"
)
val grume:Grume = Grume() // or some default constructor
)
```

or

```
data class GrumeBillesEntity(
@Embedded val billes: List<BilleEntity>,
@Relation(
    parentColumn = "id_grume",
entityColumn="id_grume"
)
val grume:Grume
) {
    constructor(): this(emptyList(), Grume())
}
```